What is the history behind the four different "official-looking" icons seen in the wild for Yellow Book CDs?
While building a wall of nostalgic logos, I realized that one of the "Compact Disc" logo variants I was certain I remembered...

...had no vector logo files anywhere on the Internet and, it turned out, was even hard to search up in the form of disc silkscreen shots. Instead, I kept finding another one ("Compact Disc Data Storage") that I didn't remember...

Then, when I was going through my collection of CD-ROMs to find something to scan and vector-trace, I found another one: Compact Disc Computer Data.

...and all four were sharing space with an un-adorned "Compact Disc" for discs without audio tracks.

(Plus a one-off that stuck "CD-ROM" below the "Compact Disc" and another one-off that I forgot to keep a record of which stuck either "Win95" or "Windows 95" under it.)
Intrigued, I decided to survey all my discs to see if maybe some or all of them were just specific publishers' in-house counterparts to the flashier "CD-ROM" icons that showed up on some jewel cases.
However, from the discs in my "loose jewel-cased games" shelf (i.e. don't have the box anymore if it was boxed, not sleeved or keep-cased, not in my "duplicates" box of different releases of the same thing, not on the other shelf where I keep non-games),  that doesn't appear to be the case.
While "Compact Disc Computer Data" looks like it might be an in-house choice that another Adventure Game publisher either copied or received in an acquisition, "Compact Disc", "Compact Disc Digital Data", and "Compact Disc Data Storage" all seemed to be in broad use.
...and sorting them chronologically also doesn't suggest that there was a standard which changed over time, with examples of all four being present from 1995 right through to the early-to-mid 2000s when they started to get replaced with that "PC CD" badge.



Game
Developer
Publisher/Label
Copyright
Logo Type




Return to Zork
Infocom
Activision
1993
Compact Disc


Out Of This World
Delphine Software
Interplay Valueware
1993
Compact Disc Data Storage


Jill of the Jungle
Epic Megagames
Romware
1993
Compact Disc


Dune (OEM)
Cryo
Virgin Games
1993
Compact Disc


Day of the Tentacle
LucasArts
Virgin Interactive
1993
Compact Disc Digital Data


PowerHits: Battletech
Activision/Infocom
Activision
1994
Compact Disc


BlackThorne
Blizzard Productions
Interplay
1994
Compact Disc Data Storage


Voyeur
Philips POV Entertainment
Interplay
1994
Compact Disc Data Storage


Jazz Jackrabbit CD
Epic Megagames
Romware
1994
Compact Disc


The Journeyman Project Turbo!
Presto Studios
Sanctuary Woods
1994
Compact Disc Data Storage


D&D: Dark Sun: Wake of the Ravager
SSI
Tring International
1994
Compact Disc


Epic Pinball: The Complete Collection
Epic Megagames
WizardWorks
1994
Compact Disc Digital Data


Pitfall: The Mayan Adventure
Activision
Activision
1995
Compact Disc


Jewels of the Oracle
ELOI
Discis
1995
Compact Disc Computer Data


The Bitmap Brothers Compilation
The Bitmap Brothers
Renegade Software
1995
Compact Disc


Sid Meier’s Railroad Tycoon
MicroProse
RomZon!
1995
Compact Disc Data Storage


MechWarrior 2 for Windows 95
Activision
SoftKey
1995
Compact Disc Digital Data


The Ultimate Add On Collection for Doom/Doom II
Microforum
SoftKey
1995
Compact Disc Digital Data


Wrath of Earth
Addix Software
SoftKey
1995
Compact Disc Digital Data


Fuzzy’s Cosmic Space Golf
Pixel Painters
Wiz Technology
1995
Compact Disc


D!Zone 150
Simply Silly Software
WizardWorks
1995
Compact Disc Digital Data


Raptor: Call of the Shadows
Apogee Software
WizardWorks/FormGen
1995
Compact Disc Digital Data


G-NOME
7th Level
7th Level
1996
Compact Disc


MechWarrior 2: Ghost Bear’s Legacy
Activision
Activision
1996
Compact Disc


Logical Journey of the Zoombinis
Broderbund
Broderbund
1996
Compact Disc Digital Data


Putt-Putt Saves The Zoo
Humongous Entertainment
Humongous Entertainment
1996
Compact Disc Digital Data


Tempest 2000
Atari
Interplay
1996
Compact Disc Data Storage


Shadoan
Virtual Image Productions
Interplay
1996
Compact Disc Data Storage


Q2 Version 2.0
Micro Star Software
Micro Star Software
1996
Compact Disc Data Storage


V For Victory
Atomic Games
SoftKey
1996
Compact Disc Data Storage


Make the Grade! Vol. 4
The Learning Company
SoftKey
1996
Compact Disc Data Storage


TerraNova
Looking Glass
Virgin Interactive
1996
Compact Disc


3 Skills of the Toltecs
Revisitronic
Warner Interactive
1996
Compact Disc


Heavy Gear
Target Games
Activision
1997
Compact Disc Digital Data


Earthworm Jim
Activision
Activision
1997
Compact Disc Digital Data


Sonic CD for PC
SEGA Entertainment
Expert Software
1997
Compact Disc Data Storage


Descent
Parallax Software
Interplay
1997
Compact Disc Data Storage


Alien Carnage
Gee Whiz!
Microforum/FormGen
1997
Compact Disc


Lands of Lore: Guardians of Destiny
Westwood
Westwood
1997
Compact Disc Digital Data


Classic Text Adventure Masterpieces
Infocom
Activision
1998
Compact Disc


Math Rabbit
The Learning Company
SmartSaver
1998
Compact Disc Digital Data


The Chessmaster 4000
The Learning Company
SoftKey
1998
Compact Disc Digital Data


Dune 2000
Westwood
Westwood
1998
Compact Disc Digital Data


Drakan: Order of the Flame
Surreal Software
Psygnosis
1999
Compact Disc


Jazz Jackrabbit 2: Holiday Hare
Gathering of Developers
SmartSaver
1999
Compact Disc Digital Data


The Crystal Key
Earthlight Productions
Dreamcatcher Interactive
2000
Compact Disc Computer Data


Traitor’s Gate
Daydream Software
Dreamcatcher Interactive
2000
Compact Disc Computer Data


Unreal Tournament: Game of the Year Edition
Digital Extremes/Epic Games
Infogrames
2000
Compact Disc


Close Combat: A Bridge Too Far
Microsoft
SmartSaver
2000
Compact Disc Digital Data


Aliens vs. Predator: Gold Edition
Rebellion
20th Century Fox Interactive
2001
Compact Disc Digital Data


Emperor: Battle for Dune
Westwood
EA Games
2001
Compact Disc Digital Data


Zoombinis Mountain Rescue
The Learning Company
SelectSoft
2001
Compact Disc Digital Data


Aliens vs. Predator 2
Monolith
Sierra/20th Century Fox Interactive
2001
Compact Disc Data Storage


Auryn Quest
Discreet Monsters/Attaction
Dreamcatcher Interactive
2002
Compact Disc


GTA2
Rockstar Games
Global Star Software
2002
Compact Disc Digital Data


Warhammer 40,000: Dawn of War
Relic
THQ
2004
Compact Disc


Kid Pix Deluxe 4 Home Edition
The Learning Company
Riverdeep
2005
Compact Disc Data Storage



Does anyone have any insight into what was going on here? Was this just a case of a lack of guidance resulting in a detente between three competing de facto standards?

The 1999 Philips CD Logo Guide says yellow book CD-ROMs should use the "Compact Disc" logo.  They include "Compact Disc/Data Storage" as an example of an invalid logo.

@KelvinSherlockI think you could post an answer based on that document. What a cool read. Somehow those logos still drum up some level of excitement in me about it all... even though those days are long gone.

Did the logo guide specify minimum space around it, or how would it suggest that a disk be labeled to indicate e.g. "Windows 95/NT" or "Macintosh"?

@KelvinSherlock Just stumbled across the same guide, plus a less explicit webpage It would be really useful if you put your comment into an answer. After all, Philips is the copyright and trademark holder for that logo, so their guide should be the most authoritative source there is.

@supercat, yes the Guide specifies a Clear Zone which must be uniform background.  And doesn't allow for including a target platform name within the logo area.  It's an easy read - I recommend following Kelvin's link.
